# Why isn't this reserveSeat() method working?

Tags: java

I'm doing an airline project for my class that will creates 10 seats and they have a seat number, a first class or a coach seat and say whether it's empty or not. First I have to create a `Seat` class and then an `Airplane` class to store an array of 10 seats. First, I'm doing the seat class and before I go on to the `Airplane` class, I want all my methods to work before I construct the `Airplane` class. But I have a problem with one of my methods, the `reserveSeat()` method. All seats start out empty. This method will change the seat from empty to reserved.

Here's my code so far,

Seat Class

```
public class Seat {

    private int seatNum;
    private String seatType;
    private boolean state;

    public Seat(int seatNum, String seatType)
    {
        this.seatType = seatType;
        this.seatNum = seatNum;
        this.state = true;
    }
    public int getSeatNum() 
    { 

        return seatNum;

    }

    public String getSeatType()
    {
        return seatType;
    }

    public void reserveSeat() 
    {
        state= false;
    }

    public void cancelSeat() 
    {

    state = true;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String str;
        String str2;

        if (state=true)
            str= "empty";

            else
                str = "reserved";

        str2 = seatNum + " \t" + seatType + " \t" + str;
        return str2;
    }



    public boolean isSeatEmpty() {


        if (state == true) 
            return true;
        return state;

        }
}
```

Application Class:

```
package proj6;

public class Project6 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Instiating a seat object with the seat number and the type of seat.
        Seat theSeat = new Seat(11, "Coach");
        System.out.println(theSeat.toString());

    }
}
```

When I first output the seat, it outputs "11    Coach   empty" which is correct. But when I call the `reserveSeat()` method, it still says the seat is empty. Why is that?

Comment: CS 101 mistake:  You can return the boolean explicitly, no need to use an if statement! :)

Comment: @Makoto not technically a *mistake*, but I agree it is poor style and an anti-pattern

Comment: @Bohemian it's worse than that, the OP is using `if(x = true)` which is _always_ `true`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider oh yes! A classic example of why it's an anti-pattern. If there's no code, it can't be wrong. (I prefer it because it's much less code, and *less code is good* is one of my mantras

Answer (score 5):

You are doing an assignment inside your if statement (inside your toString() function). You mean to use `if (state == true)` not `if (state = true)`.

Actually state is a Boolean already so `if (state)` would be the same as `if (state == true)`

Comment: ..or just `if (state)` instead of `if(state == true)`

Comment: OMG thank you! I feel so dumb

Comment: @Hovercraft, yeah I caught that right after I hit submit (typing on iPhone so edits come a little slower)

Comment: I thought Java protected against that mistake automatically?

Comment: Use [yoda conditions](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/) to make it harder to make this mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are missing a `=` sign in your `if` (so that instead of comparing you set the state). Nevertheless, this is not a Spot-My-Typo forum and in my opinion the question doesn't fit here.

Comment: Your answer is just fine, save for the "forum" remark.

Comment: @Makoto: your comment is 100% fine, because you are entitled your own opinions. In my humble opinion the question is too localized and I voted to close it.